# Download the file by touching the lazy column items at the same time in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list and when I touch an item, I want the file related to that item to be downloaded.
I wrote the code to download the file, but I have a problem.
The user may touch several items at the same time and want to download them at the same time.
The problem with my code is that when I touch several items at the same time, the download operations interfere with each other.

ViewModel class:

```
class BusinessViewModel(private val userRepository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val downloadSqliteDatabaseData: MutableState<State<String>> = mutableStateOf(State.Empty)
    fun downloadSqliteDatabase(file: File?, businessId: Long) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userRepository.downloadSqliteDatabase(businessId).onStart {
                downloadSqliteDatabaseData.value = State.Loading
            }.catch {
                downloadSqliteDatabaseData.value = State.Error("ERROR", MyHttpStatusCode.NetworkError)
            }.collect {
                downloadSqliteDatabaseData.value = when (it.status) {
                    HttpStatusCode.OK -> {
                        try {
                            val data: ByteArray = it.body()
                            file?.writeBytes(data)
                            State.Success("", it.status)
                        } catch (ex: Exception) {
                            State.Error("ERROR", MyHttpStatusCode.ConvertDataError)
                        }
                    }

                    MyHttpStatusCode.InvalidUser -> {
                        State.Error("ERROR", it.status)
                    }

                    else -> {
                        State.Error("ERROR", it.status)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compose function:

```
    val downloadSqliteDatabaseData by remember { viewModel.downloadSqliteDatabaseData }
    
    DisposableEffect(downloadSqliteDatabaseData) {
        when (downloadSqliteDatabaseData) {
            is State.Empty -> {}
            is State.Loading -> {
                //downloadDatabaseLoading.value = true
            }

            is State.Success -> {
                //downloadDatabaseLoading.value = false

            }

            is State.Error -> {
                println("Error")
                //downloadDatabaseLoading.value = false

            }
        }

        onDispose {

        }
    }
    
    LazyColumn(
        state = lazyListState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(
            items = businessList,
            key = { _, item -> item.id },
        ) { index, item ->
            ClickBox(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 15.dp, end = 15.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(120.dp),
                onClick = {
                    
                    val dbPath = File("test.txt")
                    
                    viewModel.downloadSqliteDatabase(dbPath, item.id)



                }
            ) {
                //....
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You make the current file to download the focus of the whole state of the UI.

```
val downloadSqliteDatabaseData: MutableState<State<String>>
```

If you want to handle **multiple**, you need pass it to down to the state of the item in the list.

```
sealed class BusinessState {
    object Loading : BusinessState()
    data class Loaded(val items: List<DatabaseUiItem>) : BusinessState()
}

data class DatabaseUiItem(
    val id: Long,
    val path: String,
    val state: BusinessItemState = BusinessItemState.None
)

sealed class BusinessItemState {
    object None : BusinessItemState()
    object Loading : BusinessItemState()
    object Loaded : BusinessItemState()
    object Error : BusinessItemState()
}
```

Here is the rest of the working example

```
class BusinessViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    private val failed: MutableStateFlow<List<String>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
    private val inProgress: MutableStateFlow<List<String>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
    private val downloaded: MutableStateFlow<List<String>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())

    private val _state: MutableStateFlow<BusinessState> = MutableStateFlow(BusinessState.Loading)
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()

    init {
        val items = flowOf(listOf(0L to "test_0.txt", 1L to "test_1.txt", 2L to "test_2.txt", 3L to "test_3.txt"                 )
        )
        // Here I am going to assume that you are fetching the initial list from somewhere
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            delay(200)
            combine(items, inProgress, failed, downloaded) { items, progress, errors, loaded ->
                BusinessState.Loaded(items = items.map { (id: Long, path: String) ->
                    DatabaseUiItem(
                        id = id,
                        path = path,
                        state = when {
                            loaded.contains(path) -> BusinessItemState.Loaded
                            progress.contains(path) -> BusinessItemState.Loading
                            errors.contains(path) -> BusinessItemState.Error
                            else -> BusinessItemState.None
                        }
                    )
                })
            }.collect { newState ->
                _state.update { newState }
            }
        }
    }

    fun downloadSqliteDatabase(file: String?, businessId: Long) {
        if (file == null) return
        inProgress.update { oldList -> mutableListOf<String>().apply { addAll(oldList) } + file }
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            downloadDatabase(file).onSuccess {
                inProgress.update { oldList -> mutableListOf<String>().apply { remove(file) } }
                downloaded.update { oldList -> mutableListOf<String>().apply { addAll(oldList) } + file }
            }.onFailure {
                inProgress.update { oldList -> mutableListOf<String>().apply { remove(file) } }
                failed.update { oldList -> mutableListOf<String>().apply { addAll(oldList) } + file }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun downloadDatabase(file: String): Result<String> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            delay(3000L)
            if (file == "test_1.txt") {
                throw Exception("")
            }
            Result.success(file)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Result.failure(ex)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BusinessList(
    items: List<DatabaseUiItem>,
    onItemClick: (String, Long) -> Unit
) {
    LazyColumn() {
        itemsIndexed() { index, item ->
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                onClick = { onItemClick(item.path, item.id) }
            ) {
                Text(text = item.path)
                when (item.state) {
                    BusinessItemState.Error -> Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Error, contentDescription = null)
                    BusinessItemState.Loaded -> Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Check, contentDescription = null)
                    BusinessItemState.Loading -> CircularProgressIndicator()
                    BusinessItemState.None -> Unit
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```